# NSTableView WILL NOT RELOAD

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

Hey guys, so in my newest program I use an NSTableView to display words on the left, and thier definitions on the right. these words and definitions are load from a .plist file, and at application startup the table view loads these words and definitions and displays them just fine. My problem comes in when the user tries to add a word and definition using the text boxes and buttons, the word is actually added to the .plist, meaning the method is running fine, but the table view refuses to display the new line. only until after i quit the program and reopen it does the tableview display the new line. I tested to see if the table view was connected properly by sending it other messages such as selectedRow and dataSource, all came back with responces, and proper responces at that. Currently the class that is used as the dataSource and delegate is a subclass to my main class with all my varibles and dictionaries. (I am big on using as little classes as possible). Lastly I tried inserting noteNumberOfRowsChanged in before reloadData, but still nothing.

I have tested everything and it just seems that the reloadData method is not initiating anything. Like I said, my table view is being sent the message, the new info is actually being added to the dicitinoary adn array, the amount of rows is being updated by the count method, and what proves it even more is that when the program is restarted it displays everything just fine. below is the relevent code, where currentWordList and currentDefitionList are the Array and Dictionary suppying the data to the dataSource, and editLibraryCardList is the NSTableView I am trying to reload.

the dataSource class code:

```
@interface EditorDataTable : SAT_Vocab_MacController {
    IBOutlet NSTableColumn *editLibraryWordColumn;
    IBOutlet NSTableColumn *editLibraryDefinitionColumn;
}

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row;

@end

@implementation EditorDataTable

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return ([currentWordList count]);
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row {
    if (tableColumn == editLibraryWordColumn) {
        return [currentWordList objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (tableColumn == editLibraryDefinitionColumn) {
        return [currentDefinitionList valueForKey:[[currentWordList objectAtIndex:row]lowercaseString]];
    }
}

@end
```

method that adds the word to the list:

```
- (IBAction) editLibraryAddWordToLibrary: (id) sender {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        currentWordList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:userSATWordListPath];
        currentDefinitionList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:userSATDefinitionListPath];
    }

    [currentWordList addObject:[[editLibraryNewCardWordInput stringValue]capitalizedString]];
    [currentDefinitionList setObject:[editLibraryNewCardDefinitionInput stringValue] forKey:[[editLibraryNewCardWordInput stringValue]lowercaseString]];

    aWordCounter = [currentWordList indexOfObject:[[editLibraryNewCardWordInput stringValue]capitalizedString]];

    [aWordLabel setStringValue: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [currentWordList objectAtIndex: aWordCounter]]];
    [aDefinitionLabel setStringValue: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""]];

    [currentWordList writeToFile:userSATWordListPath atomically:YES];
    [currentDefinitionList writeToFile:userSATDefinitionListPath atomically:YES];

    [cardCountdownNumber setStringValue: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", ([currentWordList count] - (1 + aWordCounter))]];

    [editLibraryCardList noteNumberOfRowsChanged];
    [editLibraryCardList reloadData];
}
```

Iv'e been stuck for days and any ideas will help! Thanks.

Zach

Comment: "I am big on using as little classes as possible" This will make your iOS projects a nightmare to maintain. The iOS frameworks are designed to have many focused classes. By trying to cram everything into as few classes as possible, you're going to be fighting the frameworks every step of the way and giving yourself needless headaches. Don't fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging into your selectRowAtIndexPath method to make sure the reload occurs? (after you call [tableView reloadData] should be able to see this)  Are you using UITableViewController?

If you wanted a callback after reload to know when its done, you could try:

```
[tableView reloadData];
    [self performSelector:@selector(selectRowAtIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, i moved my code from the dataSource subclass to the main class, and it worked. i guess you cannot subclass the dataSource. Hope this helps!